# What are the different components of the Keepass’s UUID field? Is there any use of the second UUID component?

Tags: keepass

We know that KeePass generates a UUID field for every entry in your database. One can access the contents of the UUID at the bottom of the Properties tab in the Edit Entry screen. Here are some actual UUIDs that KeePass has generated for some of my entries.

1. `FDBCA832239BA64BA6383E01C1C48B35, /byoMiObpkumOD4BwcSLNQ==`
2. `C445D7D780F83148AE5D400154A68323, xEXX14D4MUiuXUABVKaDIw==`
3. `9D19BDA171B8C642B82F1FFF447577C4, nRm9oXG4xkK4Lx//RHV3xA==`

It looks like this field has two components that are separated by a comma character followed by a space character. The entire field ends with two equal sign (=) characters. The first component contains 32 characters and is composted of upper case alphabets and digits. The second component is composed of 22 characters and it contains lower case alphabets, upper case alphabets, forward slashes and digits.

From the https://keepass.info/help/base/fieldrefs.html page we also know how this field can be used. But based on the examples shown on that page, it seems that only the first component of the UUID field can be used.

My question are

1. What are the different components of the UUID field? Can someone shed some light on this.
2. Is there any use of the second component?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same ID, but displayed in two different ways.

(It seems that KeePass doesn't use the standard DCE UUIDs – it just uses the term "UUID" to refer to a random 128-bit identifier that has no particular structure nor display format. Therefore it makes up its own display formats.)

So your two fields aren't *parts* of an ID – they're alternate formats for the *same* ID. The first part is the 128 bits (16 bytes) shown in hexadecimal, and the second part is the exact same bytes shown in Base64 encoding.

Comment: That does not seem to be the case. I did try to use the second component from my first example in a new entry. I put {REF:P@I:/byoMiObpkumOD4BwcSLNQ} in the password field, but the reference does not work. It just returns back {REF:P@I:/byoMiObpkumOD4BwcSLNQ} and not the password.